# WinSCPの同期の転送設定のファイルマスクで不要な履歴を削除したい

Tags: winscp

WinSCPで同期する場合に転送設定があります。
そこの項目「その他」にファイルマスクの設定箇所があり、そこで入力したものは自動的に保存されて「∨」をクリックすれば、簡単に過去のものを選択入力できるようになっています。
便利なのはいいのですが、間違ったり不要になった既存の入力が削除できず溜まって困っています。削除する方法はないでしょうか。

deleteキーやbackspaceキー、あるいはそれプラスshiftキーやctrlキーを組み合わせて削除を試みましたがだめでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI上の操作では個別に削除する方法は見当たらないので、設定ファイル等を直接編集する形になりますが、WinSCPの設定をどのように保存しているかによって対応方法が異なります。

具体的には、以下の値を確認して個別に削除することになりそうです。
(WinSCPは終了した状態で作業してください)

- **レジストリに保存している場合**
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration\History\Mask\` 以下の値
- **iniファイルに保存している場合**
  対象のファイル: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\WinSCP.ini`

  ```
  [Configuration\History\Mask]
  0=*.tar
  1=*.*
  ```

Comment: こちらのほうに入っていました。
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Configuration\History\IncludeMask
ありがとうございました！